# How to add md5 functions in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to set my password field type to md5 in phpMyAdmin. I thought that there was a function drop down option that had MD5 in it but I cannot see it.

I've been looking online for a solution to this for a few days now, I've tried everything I can think, but still no luck.

Here is what i can see: http://imageshack.com/a/img834/9062/gmo7.jpg

How can I add md5 type to my field type password?

Comment: The password isn't of type md5 it is a text field .... you md5 the values before you put them in.

Comment: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: I believe in the Insert page, there is a drop-down menu against text fields - that might well have MD5 in it. How is your password field defined?

Answer (score 1):

From the [MySQL Docs..](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html)

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a
>   default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must
>   be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression.

So what you are trying to do is ***not possible***.

---

You can alternatively use a trigger to achieve this.,(*I don't recommend this anyway*) However , `md5()` is not a recommended hashing algorithm anymore.

The recommended way would to use the [`crypt()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) hashing functions in PHP or, if you are running 5.5+, [`password_hash()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). There is a [drop-in replacement](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) for the latter too, for users running 5.3.7+ but prior to 5.5. Any of these approaches will allow you to create the hash of your password and then push it to your table from the query.

Answer (score 1):

Set you field in phpmyadmin to VARCAHR and a length of 32

then simple as an example

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id, role FROM users WHERE 
            login = :login AND password = MD5(:password)");
    $sth->execute(array(
        ':login' => $_POST['login'],
        ':password' => $_POST['password']
    ));
```

now any values passed as a password get md5() on input

Comment: this was just an example of using md5 within a query the example just shows that the md5 takes place outside of the database

Comment: Good answer. If you have extra bits to add, please edit them into the answer, rather than adding them as comments. We tend to regard comments as ephemeral here.